# Django ImageField [Errno 13] Permission denied even though directory is writable

Tags: django, permission-denied, imagefield

I included an ImageField field in my "sponsors" model, which is set to save the uploaded image files to my_app/static/uploads/sponsor_logos, and when I try to save a record using the admin interface, I get the following error:

OSError at /admin/sponsors/sponsor/add/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Sponsor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    level_choices = (('Gold', 'Gold'), ('Silver', 'Silver'), ('Bronze', 'Bronze'))
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=level_choices)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'sponsor_logos/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And my media root is set to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/static/uploads/'
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sponsors/sponsor/add/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'awards',
 'sponsors',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  955.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  709.         obj.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  909.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  872.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  249.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  45.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  168.                 os.makedirs(directory)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  157.     mkdir(name, mode)

Exception Type: OSError at /admin/sponsors/sponsor/add/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'
```

I ran chmod 777 on the directory my_app/static/uploads/sponsor_logos, so it should be writable. Also, I ran python manage.py shell and, from there, created a new text file in the sponsor_logos directory, so the directory does seem to be writable. Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Did you try it without the trailing slash in your ImageField definition? As in:   logo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'sponsor_logos')

Comment: Got it - my media root was set wrong. Reset it to: MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/myusername/Sites/myappname/static/uploads/', works fine now

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue for me was the same as @user1933387. I had formatted my computer and changed the naming convention of where my folder was.

for example:

Old folder was called: `/Users/jimmy/...`

New folder was renamed to: `/Users/jim/...`

/Users/jimmy no longer exists and it couldn't write to it so it throws the permissions error rather than a directory not found. Confusing when trying to dig into this, especially if you don't notice error right after a change like that but if the path doesn't exist, this is the error you get.